# execute .mysql file with C

Tags: mysql, c

I have a bunch of .mysql files with more or less complex MySQL queries and 
I am looking for a way to pass the .mysql file to mysql_query.

The most comfortable solution for me would be to open the .mysql file with `fopen` and pass the pointer to `mysql_query` but i doubt this would be working.

Another way I was thinking about was to read the file line by line into a buffer and then pass the buffer to `mysql_query`. Problem with this solution is, that i need to remove all the newlines (CR, LF) from the file while reading it into the buffer and i don't know how to do that.

Maybe someone has a better solution for me? I couldn't find anything on the web for C.

A Sample .sql file:

```
SELECT 
    IF((SELECT 
                name
            FROM
                zeiterf.stdjobs
            WHERE
                nr = zeiterf.wtime.job) != '',
        (SELECT 
                name
            FROM
                zeiterf.stdjobs
            WHERE
                nr = zeiterf.wtime.job),
        job),
    IF(usr != '',
        (SELECT 
                vname
            FROM
                zeiterf.user
            WHERE
                nr = zeiterf.wtime.usr),
        NULL),
    IF(usr != '',
        (SELECT 
                nname
            FROM
                zeiterf.user
            WHERE
                nr = zeiterf.wtime.usr),
        NULL),
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tout) - TIME_TO_SEC(tin)))
FROM
    zeiterf.wtime
WHERE
    tout != 0
AND
    job != '...ENDE'
GROUP BY job , usr WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Why don't you simply pipe the contents of a file into a mysql client? `mysql < xyz.mysql`

Comment: Because i have a C program that uses the results of this queries and I just don't wan't to code the queries into the programm, so that i can change them when needed and I don't have to recompile the program.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing: execute the mysql client from within c and read the result via a socket.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I have to exec a mysql client, establish a connection, logon to the server, etc .... ?

Comment: You have to logon anyway. Certainly you have to execute a mysql client. So what? That is what it is for...   My core point: why not use the existing client? It is there, ready. It is robust, has a great documentation. Do you really thing your implementation will be better? Do you really have to implement the 54827646383th mysql client? _Why_?

Comment: Yeah, but in my prog i already have a connection. If there is a simple way to do this directly from C i would prefer that. I was just hopeing that there is a function in the MySQL/C Connector I can use to simply do that. If useing the existing mysql client is the best way, then I will of course do that. I really don't wan't to code a new mysql client.

Comment: OK, you are the boss!